# CAML Query, get item by lookup value, not by ID

Tags: caml, query

I have the value of a lookup column, but I don't have the ID, I want to query items from SharePoint list using the lookup value. How do I achieve that in CAML?

Comment: Do you want to query multiple items by lookup value?

Comment: its straight forward query. what you want to acheive?

Comment: So I want to query multiple items by lookup value? How can i do it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Default lookup query uses the value instead of lookup Id

The typical query looks like

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='RefCountry'  />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>India</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

To query by ID you have o setup `LookupId='TRUE'` attribute of `FieldRef` element

```
<FieldRef Name='RefCountry' LookupId='TRUE' />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms442728(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: How would I achieve that with "IN" clause? e.g. this doesn't work: <View Scope="RecursiveAll">
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <In>
        <FieldRef Name="FileRef" />
        <Values>
          <Value Type="Lookup"><![CDATA[/sites/site1/Shared Documents/abc.png]]></Value>
        </Values>
      </In>
    </Where>
  </Query>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="ID" />
    <FieldRef Name="FileRef" />
    <FieldRef Name="Author" />
    <FieldRef Name="Editor" />
  </ViewFields>
  <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
</View>