# Can I reach the lookup column's data with CAML query?

Tags: caml-query, caml, query, caml-designer

I want to reach the list's data. There is lookup column. I am using CAML query. But when I create a query with CAML, I am seeing look up columns like `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue[]`.I want to see clear data.

Answer (score 0):

Default lookup query uses the value instead of lookup Id.

The typical query looks like :

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='RefCountry'  />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>India</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

To query by ID you have o setup LookupId='TRUE' attribute of FieldRef element as follows :

```
<FieldRef Name='RefCountry' LookupId='TRUE' />
```

Refer this :

1. [FieldRef element (Query)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms442728(v=office.15).aspx)
2. [CAML Query, get item by lookup value, not by ID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119156/caml-query-get-item-by-lookup-value-not-by-id)

Comment: I have written the query inside my answer but its not showing here, i don't know why...but you can refer this links you will get your your for sure

Comment: so if i query with id , can i get maltiple values?

Comment: does this answers your question?